# Understanding solutions of differential equations

Tags: differential-equations

Solving $dx/dt$ = $-1/x $ gives the following solutions in Mathematica,

x(t)  = $(x_0^2 -2t)^{1/2}$;

x(t)  = -$(x_0^2 -2t)^{1/2}$

I'm able to analytically obtain the above solutions by solving the differential equation with x(0)=  $x_0$.

Can we relate the above-mentioned solutions to the values of $x_0$?

For example, when  $x_0$ > 0 which of the above solutions will hold and when  $x_0$ < 0 which of the above solutions will be valid?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try with assumptions: `{DSolve[{x'[t] == -1/x[t], x[0] == x0}, x[t], t, 
  Assumptions -> x0 > 0], 
 DSolve[{x'[t] == -1/x[t], x[0] == x0}, x[t], t, 
  Assumptions -> x0 < 0],
  DSolve[{x'[t] == -1/x[t], x[0] == x0}, x[t], t, 
  Assumptions -> x0 == 0]}`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange.  In order to learn how to use this site 
[take the tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour). When copying equations from a notebook to your question one should format using inline code  by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  It is recommended that you browse [the Markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk - more succinctly: `DSolve[{x'[t] == -1/x[t], x[0] == x0}, x[t], t, 
   Assumptions -> #] & /@ {x0 > 0, x0 < 0, x0 == 0}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's study the solution to your differential equation (second line below).

```
sol = DSolve[{x'[t] == -1/x[t], x[0] == x0}, x[t], t]

(* {{x[t] -> -Sqrt[-2 t + x0^2]}, {x[t] -> Sqrt[-2 t + x0^2]}} *)
```

We will make two functions for each of the two possible solutions. One could cut and paste the solutions, however another way is to `Evaluate` the part of `sol` corresponding to each solution.

```
x1[t_, x0_] := Evaluate[sol[[1, 1, 2]]]

x2[t_, x0_] := Evaluate[sol[[2, 1, 2]]]
```

The `Evaluate` is required to properly define the functions `x1` and `x2`. Be sure to check that

```
?x1
```

produces

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It should be clear that we don't care whether `x0` is a positive or negative Real number as the square of the negative number will result in a positive value.

Let's plot the two solutions for the cases `x0 = 1` and `x0 = 0`.

```
With[
 {
  x0 = 1
  },
 Plot[{x1[t, x0], x2[t, x0]}, {t, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
With[
 {
  x0 = 0
  },
 Plot[{x1[t, x0], x2[t, x0]}, {t, -2, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From these plots I hope it is clear that both solutions are applicable. The plot only shows results for values where the function has a Real result. That condition will be met provided:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If one is interested in Complex results, the restriction is removed and you might use `Table` to get a list of the results.

```
TableForm[
 With[
  {
   x0 = 1
   },
  Table[{t, x1[t, x0], x2[t, x0]}, {t, -2, 2}]
  ],
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"t", "x1[t]", "x2[t]"}}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]